# Deselect an Item in a Listbox when clicked in empty space

Tags: vb.net, winforms

So I am working on a software at the moment and when you click the load button to show files in a folder I want to make it where when you click in the empty white space to deselect the item. Below is the code I am using and I can't seem to get anywhere it still keeps the item selected.

```
Private Sub Listbox1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseUp
    If ListBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location) < 0 Then
        ' clear the data
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Add `ListBox1.ClearSelected()`.

Comment: Awesome thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :)